# Is there a quicker way to hide my images in the slideshow?

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow, show-hide

As the title says, I do not wish to see the images when I load my page. I've used [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/) script for my slideshow. This the the code:

```
<div id="slideshow" name="slideshow" class="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide1.jpg' alt="slide-1" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide2.jpg' alt="slide-2" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide3.jpg' alt="slide-3" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide4.jpg' alt="slide-4" class="slide">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  10000);
</script>
```

When a page loads, I can quickly see the 4 images that are used in the slideshow. After that, the jQuery script hides them, but is there a way to hide them instantly? For example:

```
<div id="slideshow" name="slideshow" class="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide1.jpg' alt="slide-1" class="slide" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide2.jpg' alt="slide-2" class="slide" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide3.jpg' alt="slide-3" class="slide" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide4.jpg' alt="slide-4" class="slide" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

What would make me able to show them again after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, basically don't let jQuery hide your images with:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();   // so remove this!!
                                      // Page is almost entirely rendered and it's
                                      // too late to hide images now
```

but use CSS instead:

```
#slideshow > div ~ div{
   display: none;
}
```

the above will only make visible the first *slide* DIV while hiding all the other next siblings.
The remaining jQuery will than do the rest for you.

CSS3 lets you use also something like:

```
#slideshow > div:not(div:first-child) {
```

you get the point.